# Hit URL for Multiple times for maximum one Minute in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function in angular which return data set with status "Continue" or "finished". I want to keep
hitting the call until status returns "finished" but for maximum one minute only. How can I achieve this in angular

```
public getLeadsResponse(key: any) {
    this._service.getLeadsData(key).subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response) {
            if (response.payload.status == "running") {
    // here if i repeate this function it will start an infinite loop if status is always "running"
                this.getLeadsResponse(key);
            }
            else if (response.payload.status == "finished") {
                this.items = res.payload.result;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `expand()`:

```
import { of, EMPTY, timer } from 'rxjs'; 
import { expand, map, filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

const makeHttpRequest$ = timer(1000).pipe(map(() => Math.random() > 0.9 ? 'finished' : 'continue'));

const source = of(null).pipe(
  expand(value => value === 'finished' ? EMPTY : makeHttpRequest$),
  filter(value => value !== null), // Ignore the first `of(null)` that triggered the chain.
  takeUntil(timer(60 * 1000)),
);

source.subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8n11jj?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: where should I put my _service call @martin? at math.random() place..

Comment: Sorry if its silly question, l new in rxjs

Comment: Instead of `makeHttpRequest$`

Comment: You have to return an Observable from `expand` so that's where you put it

Comment: @ martin at ternary operator you are using EMPY, what should I place there instead of EMPTY?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I'm using `EMPTY` to stop `expand` from recursively calling its projection function.

Comment: why my function is keep calling after status is finished also

Comment: Its works but but it send few extra network calls even after status is finished..

Comment: I can't help you without a reproducible demo (on stackblitz for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227604/discussion-between-zain-ali-and-martin).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @martin's answer, you could also do a explicit timestamp check for 1 minute using RxJS [`timestamp`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timestamp) operator.

I've used RxJS `timer` to emit every 'n' timeunits and switch to the HTTP request for it's each emit using `switchMap` operator.

Try the following

```js
import { timer } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map, timestamp, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

public getLeadsResponse(key: any) {
  const now = Date.now();

  const subscription = timer(0, 6000).pipe(  // <-- adjust polling frequency
    switchMap(_ => this._service.getLeadsData(key)),
    timestamp(),
    map((data: { timestamp: number; value: any }) => {
      if (data.timestamp - now < 60000) {               
        return data.value;
      } else {
        subscription.unsubscribe();  // <-- close subscription if 1 min has elapsed
      }
    }),
    filter(response => response.payload.status == "finished")
  ).subscribe({
    next: response => {
      this.items = res.payload.result;
      subscription.unsubscribe();  // <-- close subscription if status is "finished"
    },
    error: error => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only can add a timeout to your ajax query which will "break" the connection to the server if it happens. So you won't be able to test payload result value.

You may implement the desired behavior in other ways :

- make your backend process asynchonous, sou you can perform ajax query let say every 5 seconds to check current status and the route you reach have to respond quickly and just "check operation status". then the 1 minute max check logic will be in your frontend app
- open a long polling connection that is able to send multiple message using for exemple  SSE
- Do the same thing above  using websocket.

In all cases the real design in this is that your backend server operation have to be asynchronous and it can communicate it's current status to another process / thread.

Note that at some point when designing an api you ends up doing this kind of stuff. Adding some asynchronous processing in a project is not as easy as doing simple long queries and add complexity to a project, but it has some benefits such as not overloading servers and let user interfaces be more reactive.

Comment: right. but problem is we don't have access to backend. we just have to deal with APIs. any solution with example please.

Comment: My suggestion mainly concerns backend changes that seems unpossible in your case.
In case changes are possible in your backend, you could  add a route to "register" a task to process in a database like. then another process on server backend often search for tasks to proceed, if any start a background long process and update the task status in database so another route with a task id parameter can let return task status in database. 
There are many way to implement this doing it from scrach, using task systems like celery https://docs.celeryproject.org or even more complex queues systems.